# Conditional probability is larger than 1?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am calculating the conditional probability of a bigram P(Wi|Wi-1) and my outcome is larger than 1, which is definitely incorrect.

My course of thought is:

$P(w_i|w_{i-1}) = \dfrac{P(w_{i-1}, w_i)}{P(w_{i-1})} $

and using relative frequencies, the numerator is (in Layman's terms):

$P(w_{i-1}, w_i) = $ the count of all occurrences of bigram $(w_{i-1}, w_i)$, divided by the count of all bigrams.

and the denominator is:

$P(w_{i-1}) = $ the count of all occurrences of $w_{i-1}$, divided by the count of all words.

I intuitively understand that a probability should not be over 1, yet this formula returns a conditional probability over 1 (e.g. $1.0000008611847664$). Can someone explain where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a toy example where you run into this problem. Say that you're estimating the probability of the bigram "AB" from the string "ABABAB". Then:

- There are $5$ bigrams: "AB", "BA", "AB", "BA", "AB". Since "AB" occurs three times, we estimate $\Pr[AB] = \frac35$.
- There are $6$ words: "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B". Since "A" ocurs three times, we estimate $\Pr[A] = \frac36 = \frac12$.

But then, we get $\Pr[B \mid A] = \frac{\Pr[AB]}{\Pr[A]} = \frac{3/5}{1/2} = \frac65 > 1$.

The problem is that when counting $\Pr[AB] = \frac35$, you're implicitly conditioning on the string not ending halfway through the bigram. You can fix this in one of three ways:

- Explicitly condition on that, in which case, you should also explicitly condition on that in $\Pr[A]$. In that case, we throw away the last word "B", because that word is the place where the bigram would be incomplete. Then $\Pr[AB]$ stays the same, but there are $5$ words left, so $\Pr[A]$ is now $\frac35$ as well.
- Add the $6^{\text{th}}$ bigram "B." representing the end of the string. In that case, we compute $\Pr[AB] = \frac12$ and everything also works.
- Compute $\Pr[B|A]$ differently, as $$\frac{\Pr[AB]}{\sum_x \Pr[Ax]}$$ where $x$ ranges over all possible words.

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated $P(w_{i-1},w_i)$ wrong. It will be equal to "the count of all occurrences of bigram $(w_{i−1},w_i)$ divided by the count of all words"

Comment: Thank you. I changed my calculations and now the probability is 1.0. Which still feels incorrect.

Comment: Check your calculations..If you need more help, elaborate the problem you are working on.